# Generate box with content in header

Tags: tables, formatting, positioning

[image: Intended style]

Halo everyone, I intend to create the one as shown in the attached photo as the header of my document using TeX but I can't seem to get it right. Either my box are distorted or they can't be balance on the same line like the one shown in the attached photo. Can anyone show me the correct way if possible in doing this in tex? Flush left and right seem not working to me but being a newbie I can't certain about that.

Following recommendations by Werner, I successfully produce what I am looking for but now the right hand column first row's height got change.

See here:
[image]

with my code as shown here:

```
\fancypagestyle{myheader}{%
  \fancyhf{}% clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[L]{{\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}%
    \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|*{7}{p{5mm}|}} 
      \hline
        \rule{0pt}{1.5em}S.\ Name & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\qquad} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\qquad} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\qquad} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\qquad} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\qquad} &
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\qquad} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\qquad} \\ \hline
        \rule{0pt}{1.5em}R.\ No & & & & & & & \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  }}
  \fancyhead[R]{{\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}%
    \begin{tabular}{|*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5mm}|}}
      \hline
         1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \phantom{5} \\ \hline
         &   &   &   & \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  }}
  }
```

So is there any mistake that I had done above?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a full compilable example showing what you have done so far.

Comment: @PeterGrill, mine is not successful. I did the above using Paint and move around the picture so that it looks like what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is something you can work with, that uses [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) to set the header of the page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[headheight=26pt]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fanychdr
\fancypagestyle{myheader}{%
  \fancyhf{}% clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[L]{\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|*{7}{c|}}
      \hline
      S.\ Name & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\qquad} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\qquad} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\qquad} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\qquad} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\qquad} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\qquad} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\qquad} \\ \hline
      R.\ No & & & & & & & \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  }
  \fancyhead[R]{\begin{tabular}{|*{5}{c|}}
      \hline
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \phantom{5} \\ \hline
        &   &   &   & \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  }
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
}
\pagestyle{myheader}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}​
```

[`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) is used to easily modify the page layout, adding the required `headheight` change to accommodate a double-line `tabular` in the header. [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) just provides dummy text.

The MWE above provides a `myheader` page style which you can set for only one page (using `\thispagestyle{myheader}`) or globally (as is currently done, via `\pagestyle{myheader}`). You didn't mention anything about a footer, but that can be added to the `myheader` page style. For example, adding the page number and/or a rule.

---

To increase the line width for the header `tabular`s, include the length setting of `\arrayrulewidth` in a group inside the respective headers. Also the cell widths can be modified by specifying something like `p{5mm}`, while the height is adjustable via the inclusion of a vertical "strut" using `\rule{0pt}{<height>}`:

```
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\newcommand{\clap}[1]{\makebox[0pt]{#1}}% Centered zero-width box
%...
\fancypagestyle{myheader}{%
  \fancyhf{}% clear header/footer
  \fancyhead[L]{{\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}%
    \begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|*{7}{c|}}
      \hline
      \rule{0pt}{1.5em}S.\ Name & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\qquad} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\qquad} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\qquad} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\qquad} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\qquad} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\qquad} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\qquad} \\ \hline
      \rule{0pt}{1.5em}R.\ No & & & & & & & \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  }}
  \fancyhead[R]{{\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{2pt}%
    \begin{tabular}{|*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5mm}|}}
      \hline
      \rule{0pt}{1.5em}\clap{1} & \clap{2} & \clap{3} & \clap{4} & \\ \hline
      \rule{0pt}{1.5em}  &   &   &   & \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  }}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
}
```

Note the additional braces that groups the contents and avoids it from spilling into the rest of your document. Any of these height adjustments (rule width and struts) should also be accompanied with a change in `headheight` to accommodate the increase.

Comment: may I know why I got this error message when compiled: Some PostScript specials could not be rendered when I try with a document with the above codes except I put in some text like "solutions not available" rather than the \lipsum package?

Comment: And how can I make the columns thicker in its lining just like the picture I show in my first post? The lining in this fancyheader is like normal line.

Comment: @Sandra: Does my example compile *without* problem? Are you viewing the result in Postscript or PDF format, or perhaps DVI? I've added some information regarding the `tabular` line width.

Comment: Thanks, its getting close to what I am looking for now. For the error message, it only happens when I compile it in DVI form but when I directly compile it into PDF form there is no error. Perhaps DVI could not support it. Now the next issue is how to increase the width and height of the columns? For example the column after S. Name, I suppose to write my name there using pen and there is not enough space for me so I would like to modify the height and width of the columns. Is that possible? Thanks again, Werner.

Comment: @Sandra: I've added a vertical strut to increase the row height. You should use `pdflatex` or `latex`->`dvips` to view the document, since DVI has limited support for content of this sort.

Comment: How about the columns on the right? I manage to adjust the height by inserting two times \rule{0pt}{1.5em} between the \hline but for the width, I can't increase it. I twist around and only column 1 of the right hand tabular increase in width not not the remaining 2 , 3 , 4 column and when I increase (a failure) the first column, all number 1, 2, 3, etc align left rather than centralized. How do I solve this?

Comment: @Sandra: For centering a column of fixed width, add `\usepackage{array}` to your document preamble and use the following column type: `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}` where you can modify `1cm`. If you want this to hold for all 5 columns, use `|*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}|}`

Comment: thanks again. I followed as directed and now the height of the first row of the right hand column increases while the height of the second row decreases. May I know why is this so?

Comment: @Sandra: Please [edit your question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/75313/edit) and include what you've done thus far in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764). It's difficult to assess where you are in the process.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Exactly what I am looking for but don't know how to do it here at first. Thanks again. I have updated my post for your reference.

Comment: @Sandra: I've added an update to my last suggestion which inserts a vertical strut in the last tables' two lines, but also reduces the size of the elements. They were too wide to fit in the `5mm` paragraph style column. I've defined `\clap` (which may be defined by other packages, so just check what you're using).

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, Werner. Thank you so much for sharing your expertise in this area.